Quiet firing- What to do when your boss strips you of your duties
I think my boss is trying to push me out for some reason and because I have the most seniority and in a union they can not just fire me. They also do not want to tell me what the problem is. They have stripped me of most of my duties, but won't tell me what I am expected to do now. I am limited in what I can do and seem to get in trouble for the smallest things. Some of my co-workers ask why I am not doing certain things anymore, or why am I doing less then everyone else. How can "I say I will not do anything my boss has not told me to do" without seeming petty.

What do you think is the possible reason your boss did not give you any work ? How long have you been at the company ? How long has he been at the company ? Is there any conflict between you and him ?

"I [am] in a union" If only there was a group you could talk to which was there to support workers when they have a dispute with their employer.

What’s wrong with saying "my boss told me not to do this"?

In some jurisdictions, this would be considered as mobbing and, as long it can be proved at a trial, would lead to indemnities and sanctions. You might want to check with a lawyer.

Ask for everything in writing and take it to the union

Ask for your updated job/role description, and ask if the changes have gone through HR


How can "I say I will not do anything my boss has not told me to do" without seeming petty.

Simply say "I am following instructions from the boss, if you have an issue you need to take it up with him".
As you are in a union they are best placed to get to the bottom of what the problem is, if you haven't already done so get them involved ASAP.

Just state the fact:

My boss told me not to do this.

There is nothing petty about following an explicit order from your boss. In most businesses it’s literally your job.
Really, that by itself should say enough, especially if people are used to you pulling your weight. If people keep on pressing, stick to the facts:

I don’t know why. My attempts to get an explanation and new assignments were unsuccessful.

You tried to be helpful. It didn’t work. That’s it.

If you are a non-confrontational person, ask your boss for "a quick meeting".
In this meeting, ask them what is the plan because "it is clear what the goal is".
Remind them that your skills aren't being used and you'd like to get back to contributing.
If you don't get a response:

Go over their head
Bring the union into it

I am no fan of unions. But this is one case where a manager might need reminding to treat all team members appropriately.

What you do: You look for a more satisfying job, preferably without letting your boss know, meanwhile you relax, have a good rest at work, and watch your salary going in every month. If you can help out colleagues without your boss finding out, that would be a nice thing to do, but don’t do that if there is any risk. Meanwhile get some books to learn more in your job, to improve your value.

That just rewards the quiet firing and reinforces the idea that the practice works

No, the company pays. Every month.

The person leaving the job is the goal and it doesn’t matter to them if the person has a replacement job or not. To the company all that matters is getting them to quit and leaving for another job accomplishes that goal.

So you want to stay at that company? Why?

Again, if the company has a goal of getting you to quit then actually quitting allows them to accomplish that goal and they don't care if the person has a new job lined up let alone a better job. The more people that quit because of these tactics the more often they will get used because they are shown to work. If a company wants to get rid of an employee they should just fire them instead of using tricks to get them to quit.
